# assigning values to a dataframe's columns based on the values in other data frame's column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There are two dataframes:

```
df1:
id sen                a1    a2    a3     a4
1  I am here          I     am    here  
2  You are there,Bar  You  are    there  Bar
3  take your time     take your   time

df2:                 
id  sen           b1   b2   b3
1 I am here        
2 no way for this
```

I need to compare f1.sen and f2.sen, and if they are equal, fill in the b1, b2, and b3 columns using values in a1, a2, a3, and a4 columns. 
The output should be like this:

```
df2:                 
id  sen            b1   b2   b3
1   I am here      I   am    here 
2   no way for this
```

This is my code:

```
if df2['sen'].equals(df1['sen']):
    df2['b1'] = df1['a1']
    df2['b2'] = df1['a2']
    df2['b3'] = df1['a3']
```

But it does not work. Any suggestion?

I also used this:

```
if df2.sen == df1.loc[df2.index].sen: 
    df2['B1'] = df1['A1']
    df2['B2'] = df1['A2']
    df2['B3'] = df1['A3']
```

But the output is:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). How I can fix it? any suggestion?
```

Comment: Why not just merge ?

Comment: @Wen, thanks for your comment. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a left join here.

```
joined = df2.join(df1.set_index("sen"), how="left", on="sen")
```

Then assign b1 to b3 the values from a1 to a3

```
joined.b1=joined.a1
joined.b2=joined.a2
joined.b3=joined.a3
```

And remove the a* columns

```
for col in joined.columns:
    if col[0] == "a":
        del(joined[col])
```

Comment: I've revised the answer slightly - particularly the direction of the join which should provide the required answer.